BindingContext is failing in MAUI
I don't fully understand how binding context works in maui. I have MainPage that uses this datagrid:
<dataGrid:DataGridView Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Expenses}"
                       SelectionMode="None"
                       IndicatorColor="Transparent"
                       IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=TwoWay}"
                       IsLoadMoreEnabled="{Binding IsLoadMore}"
                       LoadMoreCommand="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}"
                       IsColumnHeaderVisible="False">
    <dataGrid:DataGridView.Columns>
        <dataGrid:TemplateColumn AllowSort="False">
            <dataGrid:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CategoryModel">
                    <templates:ExpenseCategoryListItemTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dataGrid:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        </dataGrid:TemplateColumn>
    </dataGrid:DataGridView.Columns>
</dataGrid:DataGridView>

And when i write x:DataType i think it should change BindingContext to that model. Then inside template:
<Grid Padding="16,16,16,0" ColumnSpacing="16" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:RoundIconComponent Grid.Column="0"
                              HeightRequest="32"
                              WidthRequest="32"
                              IconBackgroundColor="{Binding Item.IconColor}"
                              IconName="{Binding Item.IconName}"
                              DefaultIconName="ic_arrow_up_red_small"
                              IconHeightRequest="20"/>

Item.IconColor or Item.IconName is not null and values are correct. This is my RoundIconComponent.xaml:
<Border 
        BackgroundColor="{Binding IconBackgroundColor}"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50"
        StrokeThickness="0">
    <Image Source="{Binding IconName}"
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               HeightRequest="{Binding IconHeightRequest}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Border>

And this is xaml.cs:
public partial class RoundIconComponent : ContentView {
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconBackgroundColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconBackgroundColor), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultIconBackgroundColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DefaultIconBackgroundColor), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), "SteelBlue");
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconName), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconHeightRequestProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconHeightRequest), typeof(int), typeof(RoundIconComponent), 20);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultIconNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DefaultIconName), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), "shopping_bag");

    public string IconBackgroundColor { get => (string)GetValue(IconBackgroundColorProperty); set => SetValue(IconBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    public string DefaultIconBackgroundColor { get => (string)GetValue(DefaultIconBackgroundColorProperty); set => SetValue(DefaultIconBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    public string IconName { get => (string)GetValue(IconNameProperty); set => SetValue(IconNameProperty, value); }
    public string DefaultIconName { get => (string)GetValue(DefaultIconNameProperty); set => SetValue(DefaultIconNameProperty, value); }
    public int IconHeightRequest { get => (int)GetValue(IconHeightRequestProperty); set => SetValue(IconHeightRequestProperty, value); }

    public RoundIconComponent() {
        this.BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

I will be grateful if someone can tell me why its not working here and what i can do
Edit:
i have only set BindingContext in MainPage:
public MainPage(MainViewModel mainViewModel, IUserContext userContext, ISettingsStore settingsStore) {
    BindingContext = _mainViewModel = mainViewModel;

I dont have bindings set in Template nor in component itself. If i remove my RoundIconComponent and write everything manually, then it resolves binding perfectly.

x:DataType is just a helper that tells VS/Intellisense what type you are using, and is also used for compiled bindings.  It does NOT actually change the BindingContext of the element.    You need to post the code where you are setting the BindingContext and the relevant code from the model

I have edited post and included part where i set BindingContext

The reason this does not work is simple actually, you are assigning the BindingContext of the custom control in your constructor, which gets overridden as soon as you use this inside a Page, as the page's context is automatically assigned to all controls that are part of the page, the correct way of creating custom control in MAUI that use binding is to use the Source of your binding as the current control so in your case your custom control would look like this :
public partial class RoundIconComponent : ContentView 
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconBackgroundColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconBackgroundColor), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultIconBackgroundColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DefaultIconBackgroundColor), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), "SteelBlue");
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconName), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), string.Empty);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconHeightRequestProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconHeightRequest), typeof(int), typeof(RoundIconComponent), 20);
    public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultIconNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DefaultIconName), typeof(string), typeof(RoundIconComponent), "shopping_bag");

    public string IconBackgroundColor { get => (string)GetValue(IconBackgroundColorProperty); set => SetValue(IconBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    public string DefaultIconBackgroundColor { get => (string)GetValue(DefaultIconBackgroundColorProperty); set => SetValue(DefaultIconBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    public string IconName { get => (string)GetValue(IconNameProperty); set => SetValue(IconNameProperty, value); }
    public string DefaultIconName { get => (string)GetValue(DefaultIconNameProperty); set => SetValue(DefaultIconNameProperty, value); }
    public int IconHeightRequest { get => (int)GetValue(IconHeightRequestProperty); set => SetValue(IconHeightRequestProperty, value); }

    public RoundIconComponent() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

And its XAML would access its code behind like this:
<ContentView
.
.
.
x:Name="this">
   <Border 
        BackgroundColor="{Binding IconBackgroundColor,Source={x:Reference this}}"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 50"
        StrokeThickness="0">
       <Image Source="{Binding IconName,Source={x:Reference this}}"
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               HeightRequest="{Binding IconHeightRequest,Source={x:Reference this}}"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />
   </Border>
</ContentView

Once you do this, you don't need to assign the BindingContext to itself and you can use this control pretty much anywhere

i tried your solution but always getting "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'" and in console it says
[DOTNET]       'IconName' property not found on 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ReferenceExtension', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image.Source'
[BindingDiagnostics] 'IconName' property not found on 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ReferenceExtension', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Image.Source'

Did you give x:Name to your ContentView?

Oh sorry, didnt see that. Thank you so much. I just really don't know why do i need to write x:Name just to refer code behind. I thought xaml and code behind are tightly coupled.

That's the thing it's not tightly coupled as it should not be, why would you give a reference to something in your code that you will not need 99.99% of the time?
